# Is there any problem using Sass @foward and @use withing react-create-app?

Tags: reactjs, sass

[Sass @forward @use,within react app, VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWwZd.png)

I've watched a video that a guy said you should use @import instead and he tried to use @forward and @use and he got an error but for me it worked fine the styles were applied normally, I wonder if it will result in some conflict when I build the app for production. If someone know something about it please let me know.

Comment: `@use` and `@forward` are only compatible with Dart Sass. The person of the video probably uses another SASS implementation not compatible with these rules.

Comment: oh yeah, he was using node-sass, that's why, thanks!